# How can I calculate sheet automatically when changing color of cell or at a certain interval?

Tags: excel, vba

I followed this guide: https://www.exceltrick.com/how_to/sum-cells-based-on-background-color/?

It works, but when I change the color of a cell the formulas are not calculated automatically. This is because Excel only calculates when changing a value in a cell or when manually prompted to do so.

So is there a way to calculate sheet automatically when changing color of cell or calculate it at a certain interval?

**Edit:**

`Application.Volatile` only makes the function be called when any cell is recalculated.

`Worksheet_Change` event is only called when any cell is recalculated.

Code:

```
Function SumByColor(CellColor As Range, rRange As Range)
Dim cSum As Long
Dim ColIndex As Integer
ColIndex = CellColor.Interior.ColorIndex
For Each cl In rRange
  If cl.Interior.ColorIndex = ColIndex Then
    cSum = WorksheetFunction.Sum(cl, cSum)
  End If
Next cl
SumByColor = cSum
End Function
```

Comment: Application.OnTime ... that might help you.

Comment: Could you post your code and tell us if its in a standard module or in the `Worksheet_Change` event please.

Comment: @ZackE I think it's a standard module, how do I add it to this event you speak of?

Comment: In order for the function to work you will need to refer to the function in the Worksheet Object when a cell or range of cell changes that way the function runs every time the cell color changes.  The Worksheet Objects are located in VBA under the Microsoft Excel Objects (There will be a list of Sheet1, Sheet2 etc etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to solve this.

The first way is to simply recalculate the entire sheet automatically at an interval: https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/505713-calculating-sheet-every-2-minutes.html

The second way is to use `Worksheet_SelectionChange` and if any of the dependents of the previous selection uses the `SumByColor` function then calculate them. You could also just call `Application.CalculateFull`, but this is expensive and could be annoying if you navigate the spreadsheet with the arrow keys.

```
Public PreviousActiveCell As Range
Public Locked As Boolean

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Locked Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If Not PreviousActiveCell Is Nothing Then
        'If PreviousActiveCell has no dependents this will raise an error.
        'There is no way to check if PreviousActiveCell has dependents without triggering the error.
        On Error GoTo SetPrevious
        'DirectDependents will call this function, avoid endless recursion
        Locked = True
        For Each dependent In PreviousActiveCell.DirectDependents
            If InStr(dependent.Formula, "SumByColor") Then
                dependent.Dirty
            End If
        Next dependent
    End If
SetPrevious:
    Locked = False
    Set PreviousActiveCell = Target
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

I have a similar function in one of my files, worked with

```
 Application.Volatile
```

Below your Dim definition. 
Slows down the file, but if it's not too big, it does the trick.

Comment: Already tried this. It makes the cell be recalculated whenever any other cell on the sheet is calculated. This does not include things like changing the background color of a cell.